# "add-to list: command not found" in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to execute these tree lines in ubuntu's terminal:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "{directoryfile}")
(require 'haskell-mode)
(require 'tidal)
```

But when I type the second line I get the message

add-to list: command not found

What might solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add-to-list` is an emacs lisp function, it is not a shell command.

When you put that in the terminal then the shell tries to interpret it as shell commands. Parenthesized sets of commands are valid, so the first thing it tries to do is run `add-to-list` as a program, builtin, shell alias, etc. -- but can't find it so issues the *command not found* error.

Try putting your commands from the question in an emacs session. (I can't say where / in what context exactly, since I'm not much of an emacs user)